# Get from String the first value with random digits

Tags: java, string, replace, substring

In my application i receive a String like this:

```
String1 = "[6, I.3, Contaminación Mecánica, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 196.875, 0.0, 196.875]";
String2 = "[16, E.19, Errores de los usuarios, 0.0, 0.0, 3281.25, 0.0, 0.0, 3281.25]";
```

From this strings i need only the first value (from String1 and String2). This is solved, with this code where you get the first two digits:

```
    String Amenaza = InformeAmenazasAGR.get(i).toString();
    Amenaza = Amenaza.substring(1,3);
    Amenaza = Amenaza.replace(",","");
```

Now i can receive this string too

```
 String3 = "[39854, R.01, Robo Outdoor, 0.0, 84000.0, 24500.0, 24500.0, 0.0, 133000.0]";
```

I tried to use

```
    String Amenaza = InformeAmenazasAGR.get(i).toString();
    Amenaza = Amenaza.substring(1,6);
    Amenaza = Amenaza.replace(",","");
```

but when the first value only has 1 digit, obtains chars of the second value and this code can has more than 5 digits. How i can obtain only the first value if has a random number of digits?.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Using substring/indexOf (preferred way if you ask me)**

```
String firstNumber = string1.substring(1, s1.indexOf(','));
```

The first argument (`1`) makes sure you don't include the `[` character, and the second argument is the index of the first `,` character.

**Using regular expressions (useful if you want to generalize it to include other numbers**

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\[(\\d+),");
Matcher m = p.matcher(s1);
m.find();
System.out.println(m.group(1));
```

Note that the pattern object can be reused for multiple number-extractions.

**A little warning regarding `split`:**
It looks like the string is quite long, and you're only interested in a small portion of it. What split does is that it returns a view of the original string, so your program is still holding on to the large string. If you do this for a large number of string, you might run into memory unnecessary memory problems.

Comment: +1 this approach is simplest and lighter then `split` which would need to traverse entire line. Only thing I would suggest is adding reference which will hold result from `substring` since now it looks like by `substring` we are manipulating `string1` value, while in fact we are creating new string.

Comment: Thank you, i used this method. i need to manage a large number of strings so i tried to evade `split` in any moment.

Answer (score 1):

User regular expressions to find your first digit sequence.

For instance:

```
String[] input = { 
    "[6, I.3, Contaminación Mecánica, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 196.875, 0.0, 196.875]",
    "[16, E.19, Errores de los usuarios, 0.0, 0.0, 3281.25, 0.0, 0.0, 3281.25]",
    "[39854, R.01, Robo Outdoor, 0.0, 84000.0, 24500.0, 24500.0, 0.0, 133000.0]"
};
//                            | preceded by start of input and open square bracket
//                            |       | digit sequence of any length (1+ characters)
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(?<=^\\[)\\d+");
// iterating various inputs
for (String s: input) {
    // matching
    Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
    if (m.find()) {
        // printing out match
        System.out.println(m.group());
    }

}
```

**Output**

```
6
16
39854
```

Answer (score 0):

You could split the string and get the first element. Don't forget to remove the `[` character too:

```
String String1 = "[6214, I.3, Contaminación Mecánica, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 196.875, 0.0, 196.875]";

String[] split = String1.split(",");
System.out.println(split[0].replace("[", ""));
```

This approach is clear and self explained( get me the first element of the input string) and it is very useful when you want to hold a reference to the splitted string for futher accesses. If you carry only about getting the first element, I suggest the substring approach too:

```
String firstElem = String1.subString(1 , String1.indexOf(','));
```

You should not think about memory consumption unless you're dealing with many strings( more than a few millions).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
String String1 = "[645245, I.3, Contaminación Mecánica, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 196.875, 0.0, 196.875]";
String[] splitdata = String1.split(",");    
System.out.println(splitdata[0].replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z0-9., ]", ""));
```

Hope it will help you.